# Android bilinear image downscaling

Tags: android, bitmap, filtering, interpolation

I am trying to downscale a bitmap using bilinear filtering, but apparently there is something wrong in my code, because the image seems better than nearest neighbour or just using android's downsampling, but not good enough as Image Magick's biliear filter.

Do you see something wrong in my resize method?

```
private Bitmap resize(Bitmap immutable, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(reqWidth, reqHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
    float scaleFactor = immutable.getHeight() / (float) reqHeight;
    for (int x = 1; x < reqWidth - 1; x++) {
        for (int y = 1; y < reqHeight - 1; y++) {
            float sx = x * scaleFactor;
            float sy = y * scaleFactor;
            int rx = (int) (x * scaleFactor);
            int ry = (int) (y * scaleFactor);

            final int tl = immutable.getPixel(rx, ry);
            final int tr = immutable.getPixel(rx + 1, ry);
            final int bl = immutable.getPixel(rx, ry+1 );
            final int br = immutable.getPixel(rx + 1, ry+1);

            float xC1 = sx- rx;
            float xC2 = 2-xC1;

            float yC1 = sy - ry;
            float yC2 = 2 - yC1;

            xC1/=2;
            xC2/=2;
            yC1/=2;
            yC2/=2;

            final float firstAlpha = (Color.alpha(tl) * xC2 + Color.alpha(tr) * xC1);
            final float firstRed = (Color.red(tl) * xC2 + Color.red(tr) * xC1);
            final float firstBlue = (Color.blue(tl) * xC2 + Color.blue(tr) * xC1);
            final float firstGreen = (Color.green(tl) * xC2 + Color.green(tr) * xC1);

            final float secondAlpha = (Color.alpha(bl) * xC2 + Color.alpha(br) * xC1);
            final float secondRed = (Color.red(bl) * xC2 + Color.red(br) * xC1);
            final float secondGreen = (Color.green(bl) * xC2 + Color.green(br) * xC1);
            final float secondBlue = (Color.blue(bl) * xC2 + Color.blue(br) * xC1);

            int finalColor = Color.argb((int) (yC2 * firstAlpha + yC1 * secondAlpha), (int) (yC2 * firstRed + yC1 * secondRed), (int) (yC2 * firstGreen + yC1
                    * secondGreen), (int) (yC2 * firstBlue + yC1 * secondBlue));
            bitmap.setPixel(x, y, finalColor);
        }
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

[image: My Result]

while Image magick's result is this:
[image: Image magick's result]

Answer (score 2):

Android uses bilinear downscaling algorithm when ***BitmapFactory.Options::inSampleSize->BitmapFactory.decodeResource()*** is called.

So good downscaling algorithm (not nearest neighbor like) consists of just 2 steps (plus calculation of the exact Rect for input/output rectangles cropping):

1. downscale using ***BitmapFactory.Options::inSampleSize->BitmapFactory.decodeResource()*** as close as possible to the resolution that you need but not less than it
2. get to the exact resolution by downscaling a little bit using ***Canvas::drawBitmap()***

Here is detailed explanation how SonyMobile resolved this task: http://developer.sonymobile.com/2011/06/27/how-to-scale-images-for-your-android-application/

Here is the source code of SonyMobile scale utils: http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/code-example-module/image-scaling-code-example-for-android/